# Python Logging with dictConfig - "No handlers could be found"

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I am trying to setup logging on multiple modules using `logging.config.dictConfig`. I can see logging from `__main__`, but can't see any output from my modules. I feel like I'm missing something extremely basic.

Here is the directory structure:

```
settings.json
main.py
a/
`---b.py
`---__init__.py
```

Here are the contents of `settings.json`

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        }
    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        }
    },

    "loggers": {
        "a.b": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": "no"
        }
    },

    "root": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "handlers": ["console"]
    }
}
```

Here is `main.py`

```
import logging
import logging.config
import json

from a import b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    with open("settings.json", "r") as log_settings:
        log_config = json.loads(log_settings.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(log_config)
    logger.info("Hello from main!")
```

And, finally, here are the contents of `b.py`

```
import logging

print "Name of module: {0}".format(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.warning("Test warning!")
```

When running this, I get the following output:

```
Name of module: a.b
No handlers could be found for logger "a.b"
2015-10-13 18:26:12,138 - __main__ - INFO - Hello from main!
```

Why is there no handler found for a.b? I specify it in `settings.json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your code in `b.py` gets executed before your call to `dictConfig()` - it's executed at the line `from a import b`. If you move the stuff in `b.py` into a function `foo()` and call `b.foo()` from main *after* calling `dictConfig()`, you shouldn't see the `No handlers` message. You still won't see the "Test warning!" message, of course, since you've set the level to `ERROR` for that logger.

Also note that you have duplicated the `console` handler for `root` and `a.b` loggers, so you will see messages logged in `a.b` twice in the output. This is because you have set "propagate" to "no", which Python evaluates as `True`. To avoid propagation, set it to `false` in the JSON (no quotes) which will become `False` in Python.

Comment: That was the reason. Thanks!